# Java spark unable to load file from local file system in spark sql

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am newbie to spark and learning spark with java on ubuntu 18.0 with no explicit clusters.
I have data.csv file saved at local file system in java/main/resources folder.

while executing below code,

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("sparksql").master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();



Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read()
                .option("header", true)
                .csv("/media/home/work/sparksamples/src/main/resources/exams/test.csv");
```

below error is coming :

20/11/23 16:07:46 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.$anonfun$bulkListLeafFiles$1(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:195)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)

Could 20/11/23 16:07:46 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.$anonfun$bulkListLeafFiles$1(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:195)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
```

How to load file from local file system without using hdfs in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

It was due to missing hadoop-client jar in latest version - 3.3.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
```